# Alamofire: Timeout happening sometimes without any particular reason

Tags: alamofire

Sometimes when starting the app, all requests will timeout with these logs :

```
| request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x170006aa0> { URL: http://#host#/api/settings?version=1428591014 } 
| response: nil 
| json: nil
| error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "La requête a expiré." UserInfo=0x1740f0380 {NSUnderlyingError=0x174056440 "L’opération n’a pas pu s’achever. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork erreur -1001.)", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://#host#/api/settings?version=1428591014, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://#host#/api/settings?version=1428591014, NSLocalizedDescription=La requête a expiré.})
```

and here is an example of code responsible for the request call:

```
Alamofire.request(AppRouter.Settings.RetrieveAppSettings(Settings.sharedInstance.version))
  .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
  .validate(statusCode: [200])
  .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in

    if error != nil {
      // log error to local file
    }
    else {
      // do something with data
    }
}
```

When it happens, all the requests will fail with the same logs. One have to kill the app manually (home button) and restart it again and then all requests will succeed…

Anyone have some ideas plz ?

Comment: Please correct the title of the question to make it clear that you are dealing with alamofire so other users can find your question easier.

Comment: Had the same issue a couple of times. The timeout error triggers as soon as the call to the request function is called. Mushu8, did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem as far as I remember. It's a question of http connections not being allowed per default with newer versions of Xcode. I experienced the problem when switching to the Xcode-beta 7.0, but might have been earlier versions as well.

Try adding the following to your info.plist:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>--- YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE - EXAMPLE: example.com ---</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludeSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

This allows http connections to the domain you want. Add as many domains you want as key dict pairs in the dict corresponding to NSExceptionDomains.

To insert this as XML, right click info.plist and click "Open as" -> "Source code".

Then add the above XML just before the  tags at the end of the document.

Hope this works out for you :)

Comment: it does not worl for me… :-(